# What are these unknown partitions I see in gparted?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, swap

There are two partitions in my Ubuntu 12.04 setup that don't mount and are "unknown"; /dev/sda7 and /dev/sda5:

[image]

and the properties dialogue:

[image]

Is one supposed to be my SWAP partition? I have 8 GB of ram (so maybe sda7 was swap). Should I format the partitions to a certain format and somehow mark it as SWAP? Should I merge the two partitions (and the 7mb unallocated space) together?

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Yep, sda7 seems to be your swap partition... but what's in sda5? It haves almost 15 GB!

Comment: @espectalll123 I turns out they are both swap, and are encrypted and not mounting. This must have happened when I upgraded to 12.04 and I encrypted my home drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no swap, otherwise gparted would have found it.

You can start gparted as root and mark a partition as swap.

After that you should modify manually fstab

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Comment: Thanks for the response gianni. I tried to format the partition as swap while running gparted as root, but got an error: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1483214/Photos/partitions-03.png  I'll try again from a live session.

Comment: Maybe you can remove the swap from fstab, reboot and then try again

Comment: It took some work, but I got it all fixed.

Comment: From a live usb boot I deleted sda5, added all the unallocated space to my Linux partition (sda6), formatted sda7 to Linux-Swap and then added it to fstab. Because of all the partitioning my grub was broken and I couldn't boot into any OS. But I fixed this easily with Boot-Reapir - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair